# Cloud storage - Transferring data to server based on travel plans of a user (IBM) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, ibm, us20130144978, cloud-storage

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON transferring data to a server based on user travel plans** - This application from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com) seeks to patent the idea of...transferring data in cloud storage system from a data server near a user usual location to a data server near where a user plans to travel! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 12/2/2011** that discusses:

> - Moving data between servers based on user travel plans

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO involves accessing a user's calendar to figure out where he will travel and when

**TITLE: Transferring data between servers based on travel plans of a user**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A method for moving data between data servers bsaed on travel plans of a user (basically, if the user is traveling somewhere, moving some data from his "home" server to a server which is closer to the location he will be.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130144978 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130144978?dq=US20130144978A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/309,640
- **Assignee**: IBM
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 12/2/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 12/3/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130144978)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method, comprising:
>
> 1. locating a data server near a travel location of a user based on one or more travel plans of the user; and
> 2. transferring data of the user from a home data server near a home location of the user to the data server near the travel location.

In English this means:

> A method of data relocation in a cloud storage environment, comprising:
>
> 1. Locating a data server which is physically close to a location of a user based on travel plans of the user
> 2. Transferring data of the user from the home data server to the data server near the travel location

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 12/2/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming accessing the user's calendar to figure out where he will travel so data can be moved there

---

**"System for data relocation in cloud storage environments from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Seems like something Google would have (or does) do - though I'm not aware of any specific mention of it.

Comment: By transfer, can it be syncing, or is it copying over once and then deleting?

Answer (score 1):

In the late 90s, early 2000s, there were several proprietary implementations of trading/finance systems that would cache/sync data with servers in other locations (where the firm had offices) based on a mobile/desktop calender app. This was generally used for presentation prep and if large models/trade histories had to be moved for those presentations. Bandwidth/disk space limitations existed back then and the internet applications weren't very reliable, so it was worthwhile to move files when needed.

I no longer recall the specific system's names, but it gives an idea of where this could be done before.